# php/mysql how to join three tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm writing code for a school transcript system. However, I'm stuck in joining the tables which are the courses table I named 'causes', courses registered table I named 'courses_registered' and the students table 'students' actually the join works, but the problem is that data are repeated in multiples depending on how many data rows that are on the courses_registered table for example, if  have 2 courses registered, I get 4 rows echoed out from all tables instead of two. so my question is, how can i join these three tables perfectly without data being repeated, when i loop through the data. this is the table structure for the three tables.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `courses`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`course_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`course_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cl` int(255) NOT NULL,
`level` int(255) NOT NULL,
`session` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`semester` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `courses`
--

INSERT INTO `courses` (`id`, `course_code`, `course_title`, `cl`, `level`,      `session`, `semester`) VALUES
(1, 'GSS 111', 'Use of English', 3, 1, '2009/2010', '1'),
(2, 'GSS 112', 'Nigerian History', 2, 1, '2009/2010', '1');



--
-- Table structure for table `courses_registered`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `courses_registered` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`course_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
`student_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
`score` int(255) NOT NULL,
`grade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `courses_registered`
--

INSERT INTO `courses_registered` (`id`, `course_id`, `student_id`, `score`,       `grade`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 60, 'B'),
(2, 2, 2, 80, 'A');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`regno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`college` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dept` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`level` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`no_of_semesters` int(255) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dob` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`age` int(255) NOT NULL,
`mstatus` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`nationality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`religion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `students`
--

INSERT INTO `students` (`id`, `regno`, `college`, `dept`, `level`, 
    `fname`,    `lname`, `no_of_semesters`, `gender`, `dob`, `age`, 
    `mstatus`, `nationality`, `religion`, `address`, `email`, `phone`) 
 VALUES
   (2, 'MOUAU 09/14508', 'CEET', 'Electrical Electronics Engineering', 
    '1', 'Nnamdi', 'Okoro', 2, 'Male', '24-07-1989', 25, 'Single', 
    'Nigerian', 'christian', 'Okpu Umiobo road, Aba', 
    'nokoro@gmail.com', '09056733333');
```

Then this is the query

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT c.id as course_id
     , c.course_code
     , c.course_title
     , c.cl
     , c.level
     , c.session
     , c.semester
     , r.id as rid
     , r.course_id
     , r.student_id
     , r.score
     , r.grade
     , s.id
     , s.regno
     , s.fname
     , s.lname
     , s.no_of_semesters 
  FROM courses_registered r 
  JOIN courses c  
    ON r.course_id = course_id 
  JOIN students s 
    ON s.id = r.student_id 
 WHERE s.id = '$id'
 "; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Could not show students records.'. mysqli_error($con) );

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
   //echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){

      $score[] = $row['score'];
      $course_code[] = $row['course_code'];
      $course_title[] = $row['course_title'];
      $cl[] = $row['cl'];
      $grade[] = $row['grade'];
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join three tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801722/how-to-join-three-tables)

Comment: Just fyi, I doubt $id needs inverted commas. Also, if using a nice modern API like mysqli, then probably best to take a look at prepared statements too!

Answer (score 1):

Try change this

```
ON r.course_id = course_id
```

to

```
ON r.course_id = c.id
```